# Topology - Show that the given space is homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Provide a specific bijection and its inverse showing the given pair of spaces is homeomorphic.

$X = [1,2)$ and $Y = (-1,0]$ where both are given their subspace topology in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You can do this with an affine function $f(x)=ax+b$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: It can be done directly, but if you don’t see how, start with a homeomorphism from $X$ to $[-1,0)$. Then find a homeomorphism from $[-1,0)$ to $Y$ and compose the two. Both of these are very easy: just slide and flip.

Comment: Well, the only thought I had was the following:The function $f(x) = x - 2$ is a continuous mapping of $X$ onto $Y$ whose inverse, given by $g(x) = x + 2$, is continuous. So $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$.

Comment: @user62104: No, that function maps $X$ onto $[-1,0)$, not $Y$. That’s the first of the two homeomorphisms that I had in mind in my answer. Now you have to compose it with a homeomorphism from $[-1,0)$ to $(-1,0]$.

Comment: What about $f(x) = 1 - x$?

Comment: @user62104: For the bijection from $X$ to $Y$? Yes, that works nicely.

Comment: And then the inverse would be essentially the same thing. Thanks for the help. Question though. I chose $f(x) = 1 - x^2$. How does this relate to the intervals $[1,2)$ and $(-1,0]$? I kind of get it but feel like I need it explained to me.

Comment: @user62104: $1-x^2$ won’t work: it sends $[1,2)$ to $(-3,0]$. $f(x)=1-x$ sends $1$ to $0$ and $2$ to $-1$ and interpolates linearly between them, so it sends the interval $[1,2)$ to the interval $(-1,0]$. Look at the graph of the function: the domain is $[1,2)$, the range is $(-1,0]$, and the function is one-to-one. Any function with those properties would work, and linear interpolation between the endpoints is the simplest.

Comment: Oops sorry. I meant to type $f(x) = 1 - x$.

Comment: @user62104: I thought that that might have been the case, but I wasn’t sure, so I played safe and said something.